# How to Transpose header row value group by particular column value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery, unpivot

I have some data in excel in following format:

```
Cust_Name    Prod1     Prod2    Prod3     Prod4    Prod5
A            0         100      120       0        0
B            145       120      168       0        200
C            350       300      0        340       0
```

I need to convert the following format in below-mentioned report format.

I want to transpose those product in a column group by Cust_Name which has value >0 else it shouldn't be part of final output report.

I have tried many pivot option but it didn't work.

Required Output:

```
Cust_Name      Product       Price
A              Prod2         100
               Prod3         120
Total A        -             220
B              Prod1         145
               Prod2         120
               Prod3         168
               Prod5         200
Total B        -             633
C              Prod1         350
               Prod2         300
               Prod4         340
Total C        -             890
```

Comment: Have you tried using Power Query, to unpivot data and transform into a tabular data ?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - Nope, I'm not aware of power query. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Are there unique cust_names?

Comment: @FaneDuru - Yes,  It has unique cust_names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with PowerQuery.

Select any cell in your source data. Use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

The PowerQuery editor will open, like this:

[image]

Select the Cust_Name column by clicking the column header. Use Transform>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot Other Columns:

[image]

At this point, optionally filter the Value column to exclude 0.

Now use Home>Close & Load to put the data back into your workbook.

You can now create a pivot table to get your sub totals:

[image]

Here is the query from the Advanced Editor dialog in the PowerQuery editor:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Cust_Name", type text}, {"Prod1", Int64.Type}, {"Prod2", Int64.Type}, {"Prod3", Int64.Type}, {"Prod4", Int64.Type}, {"Prod5", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Cust_Name"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to pass range instead of passing product name (i.e Prod1 and so on)?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you clarify or edit your post with more detail?

Answer (score 4):

If you need a VBA solution, please test the next code. It will return in another sheet the processing result. It is designed to process as many products are on the sheet (in the headers row). The code should be very fast, all processing being done in memory:

```
Sub TransposeSummarize()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shRet As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, dict As Object
  Dim arr, arrFin, arrDict, i As Long, J As Long, k As Long, count As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set shRet = sh.Next 'use here the sheet you need returning
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row          'last row
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column
  arr = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  ReDim arrDict(UBound(arr, 2) - 2)                    'Redim the arrDict for first time
  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")      'set the Dictionary (Scripting) object
  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)                             'iterate between the array elements (rows and columns)
        For J = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)
            arrDict(J - 2) = arr(i, J)                 'fill arrDict with values on the i row
        Next J
        dict(arr(i, 1)) = arrDict                      'place the array as dictionary item
        Erase arrDict: ReDim arrDict(UBound(arr, 2) - 2) 'reinitialize the necessary array
  Next i

  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count * lastCol + 1, 1 To 3): k = 1
  'Put the Headers in the final array:
  arrFin(1, 1) = "Cust_Name": arrFin(1, 2) = "Product": arrFin(1, 3) = "Price": k = 2
  
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1             'process the dictionary keys/items and create the final array
        arrFin(k, 1) = dict.Keys()(i)
        For J = 0 To UBound(dict.Items()(i))
            If dict.Items()(i)(J) <> 0 Then
                arrFin(k, 2) = arr(1, J + 2): arrFin(k, 3) = dict.Items()(i)(J)
                count = count + dict.Items()(i)(J): k = k + 1
            End If
        Next J
        arrFin(k, 1) = "Total " & dict.Keys()(i): arrFin(k, 2) = "-": arrFin(k, 3) = count
        count = 0: k = k + 1
  Next i
  'drop the array content at once, at the end of the code:
  shRet.Range("A1").resize(k - 1, UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

I overcomplicated the above code only because I started working at it before receiving the answer regarding the unique "cust_names". I intended to use the dictionary to also process multiple such names. The next version, does not use a dictionary, anymore and extracts the final array content only processing the first one. Just playing with VBA:

```
Sub TransposeSummarizeUnique()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, shRet As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long
  Dim arr, arrFin, i As Long, J As Long, k As Long, count As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set shRet = sh.Next 'use here the sheet you need returning
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row           'last row
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'last column
  arr = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastR, lastCol)).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr) * lastCol + 1, 1 To 3)
  
  'Put the Headers in the final array:
  arrFin(1, 1) = "Cust_Name": arrFin(1, 2) = "Product": arrFin(1, 3) = "Price": k = 2

  For i = 2 To UBound(arr)                            'iterate between the array rows:
        arrFin(k, 1) = arr(i, 1)                      'fill the customer name
        For J = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)                   'iterate beteen the array columns"
            If arr(i, J) <> 0 Then
                arrFin(k, 2) = arr(1, J): arrFin(k, 3) = arr(i, J)'fill the product and its value
                count = count + arr(i, J): k = k + 1   'calculate the values sum
            End If
        Next J
        'write the balance row (Total, Sum):
        arrFin(k, 1) = "Total " & arr(i, 1): arrFin(k, 2) = "-": arrFin(k, 3) = count
        count = 0: k = k + 1                           'reinitialize the count and increment the array row
  Next i

  'drop the array content at once, at the end of the code:
  shRet.Range("A1").resize(k - 1, UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```